# Problem with Stereo Camera on one usb connect with OpenCV 4 and Python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have this cam in test (https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B01JLU20C0/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o04_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for a stero vision project.

The module has two cameras which are connected to the computer via a USB port. With this I would like to test depth detection for a project. If I only take photos, it works very well. Only the live stream doesn't work the same for both cameras. I already tried all possible resolutions, unfortunately no success. Does anyone have an idea?

THX

Windows 10, Python 3.7, CV4

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120)

# Second Cam
cap2 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)
cap2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 120)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    ret2, frame2 = cap2.read()


    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame 1',frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame 2',frame2)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have now switched to two other cameras, each of which is connected specifically to USB. Now everything works fine. I'll install them in a housing and then Stereo Vision really gets going.  As soon as I'm finished there will be everything on GitHub and Youtube..but it will take some time ;-)